# C# Convert int to little endian hex string

Tags: c#, int, substring, converters, endianness

I want to convert an int to little endian hex string. then strip off the last two zeros.

heres my int:

```
int score = 2516000;
```

result want returned:

```
20642600
```

the final string after substring

```
206426
```

What would be the easiest way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var reversedBytes = System.Net.IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(2516000); // 543434240
var hex = reversedBytes.ToString("x");                                // 20642600
var trimmed = hex.Substring(0, hex.Length - 2);
```

The `hex.TrimEnd('0')` method from the other solution will rip off ALL trailing zeros, not just the last 2.

Comment: I believe that was the intent; it just appears the example had just two. I used my psychic powers to surmise that all trailing zeros were intended. These powers are not perfect, however, and I'd happily change my answer to limit the effect of the trim should the asker indicate it.

Comment: Also note your solution trims _all_ trailing characters, regardless if they are '0' or some other character.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed it was Kevin Frei. Hi. I'm a fan of your work. I'd like to talk with you about it sometime.

Comment: Thanks I didn't take into account the possibility of there being more than 2 trailing zeros!

Comment: Note you'll get an exception if the `hex` string length is less than 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
var reversedBytes = System.Net.IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(2516000); // 543434240
var hex = reversedBytes.ToString("x");                                // 20642600
var trimmed = hex.Substring(hex.Length >= 2 
                                ? hex.Length - 2 
                                : hex.Length);                        // 206426
```

EDITED: fixed `trimmed` to match the clarification of user request.

Comment: I should have been a little more specific.. What Kevin said is right though. I'd like the length to be at exactly 6 chars. Only cutting the last two zeros.

Comment: Ah, I lose! My psychic powers have failed me!